# Sub menu not showing up on mouseover

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, navigation

Magento 1.9 - rwd Theme.

Hey guys I'd really appreciate your help on this.

I have categories in root category and in one of those categories I have sub-categories.

categories show up in top nav menu however when I mouseover on parent category drop-down doesn't show up with sub categories.

In source I do see UL with all sub-cats but they dont show up on mouseover. I've also changed Maximal Depth under Category Top Navigation from admin panel. NO LUCK is there something I may be missing?

Comment: have your sub-cat contain products ?

Comment: no, its a fresh install, without sample data.

Comment: I have added products to all sub categories and still nothing.

Comment: I have changed a package to default and dropdown works like a charm. Unfortunately that's not a case when using RWD theme ((

Comment: can you plz post your url

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work in chrome and Firefox.

small css hack:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 771px){
   li.parent:hover ul.level0{display: block;}
}
```

Or you can recompile Scss.
In *rwdOrYourTheme/scss/layout/_header-nav.scss* in line 273

```
@include bp(min-width, $bp-medium + 1) {
   .nav-primary {
      //add this line:
      li.parent:hover ul.level0{display: block;}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check in backend this attribute "Include in Navigation Menu" of sub category. If you set it is no, sub-menu can't display on navigation.

Comment: All sub categories are set to YES to display in top navigation.